# connect an input text to a slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a text input box that allows a user to enter a number. I would like to add a slider control next to it so they have the option to use a slider control. The slider would allow for quick changes, whereas the input box would allow for more precise inputs (especially in cases where there is a slider with a huge min-max range).

What is the best way to connect both of these? So if a user enters a number in the input box, the slider automatically moves its position to where that number is, and vice versa. If the user moves the slider, the input box updates to show the number that the slider is on.

this is what i have

```
const [sliderValue, setsliderValue] = useState(15)

 <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Slider 
                maximumValue={100}
                minimumValue={0}
                step={1}
                value= {sliderValue}
                onValueChange={newsliderValue => setsliderValue(newsliderValue)}  
            />
            <Text>Value:{sliderValue} </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="RFC"
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={newsliderValue => setsliderValue(newsliderValue)}
              value={sliderValue}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='characters'
            />
          </View>
```

im using the slider of react native elements, my problems are that the text input throws me the next error "Invariant violation: iinvariant violation: cannot interpolate an input which is not a number

also i cant put {sliderValue} as placeholder in the text input to show the same number as the slider

any help would be appreciated

Comment: where is Slider from? It's not from React Native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invariant violation is a result of trying to set a string to `sliderValue`. You have to use `newSliderValue => setSliderValue(parseInt(newSliderValue))`. I believe that you can use `{sliderValue}` as a placeholder. It just might not show the placeholder because the value is always set.

Comment: both answers worked pretty good, im just having a last problem, and that is that i listed a max and min value how can i prevent the user to put  a value that is higher than the setted max value?

Comment: In onChangeText, do: 

`newSliderValue => (newSliderValue <= 100 || setSliderValue(parseInt(newSliderValue)))`

Comment: this doesnt let me put any number on textimput

Comment: Sorry, it should be `&&` instead of `||`: `newSliderValue => (newSliderValue <= 100 && setSliderValue(parseInt(newSliderValue)))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `string` value from the `TextInput` to number. Change the `onChangeText` function to:

```js
newsliderValue => {
  if(!isNaN(parseInt(newsliderValue))) {
    setsliderValue(parseInt(newsliderValue))
  }
}}
```

Setting the value only if it is a number.

Comment: both answers worked pretty good, im just having a last problem, and that is that i listed a max and min value how can i prevent the user to put  a value that is higher than the max value?

Comment: if the `newsliderValue` is not in the range than just don't call the `setsliderValue`.